# How can I control the column space according number of elements with CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

For example, I'd like to use a class which has at the most 3 columns, but If I had just 2 elements, this row gonna align this elements to the center
Is it possible with CSS grid?

in the example below, I'd like to center the elements of second line

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>grid</title>
    <style>
        .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        }

        .grid > div {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/auvybejx)

Comment: Use flexbox, not grid. The picture you linked is not in a grid layout.

Comment: But I can't control at the max number of elements per row with flexbox. Because I just want 3 element at the most. The image is just an example

Comment: You can absolutely have a maximum number. Please post your attempts and we can help!

Comment: Here is an code that I'm trying, I'd like to center the seconde row

http://jsfiddle.net/auvybejx/

Comment: Can you include the code in your question?

Comment: Of course. I just did it

Comment: Like I said, use flexbox, not grid.

Comment: I'll try it, from what I’ve seen isn't possible to control the number of columns with grid

Comment: @jhpratt Can flexbox solve this without using JS?

Comment: @dasfdsa I did it with flexbox http://jsfiddle.net/zaLh7om9/

Comment: When there is only one block, it takes whole width. Good solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you can check if the row only has two elements, then:

1. Move the second element to the third column
2. Delete the middle column

This way that row will only have 2 columns, and will be aligned to center.

Comment: You can't delete columns when using grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did the result that I was looking for with flexbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>grid</title>
    <style>
        .grid {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap:wrap;
        }

        .grid > div {
            background: red;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            flex-grow: 1;    
           width: calc(100% * (1/3) - 10px - 10px);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaLh7om9/)